# Otel collector not getting logs from dotnet

Tags: .net, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have a dotnet app that pushes logs to a otel collector. Locally, with docker compose it all works, however when I try to run the same in kubernetes I only get the traces but not the logs.

In the collector logs I see this error which might be the reason:

> info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [transport] [server-transport 0xc002c53520] Closing: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: read tcp 172.16.1.45:4317->172.16.1.43:44348: read: connection reset by peer"     {"grpc_log": true}

IP .45 corresponds to the collector and .43 to the application. The direction tells me that it goes from the collector to the app, which is confusing as the app is supposed to push logs to the collector and not the other way around... What could be the reason for this?

The only difference that I can see between the local and kubernetes deployment is that the app is listening to https instead of http.

The collector config looks like this:

```
receivers:
  otlp/app:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:
exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
  prometheus: # metrics
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    send_timestamps: true
    resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
      enabled: true
    const_labels:
      exported: "collector"
  otlp/tempo:
    endpoint: tempo:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true
  loki:
    endpoint: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [ otlp/app ]
      exporters: [ prometheus ]
    
    traces:
      receivers: [ otlp/app ]
      exporters: [ otlp/tempo ]
    logs:
      receivers: [ otlp/app ]
      exporters: [ logging, loki ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was having OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT in the appsettings and not as an environment variable.